# Assigning the role while user registration Laravel

Tags: laravel, arguments, roles, registration

I'm trying to make a register page with role as a radio button(consumer, supplier, Admin)
but it show me this **error** when I test the query in postman

`Error: Class &quot;App\Http\Models\Role&quot; not found in file`

my controller:

```
 public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'first_name'=>'required|string',
            'last_name'=>'required|string',
            'email'=>'required|string|unique:users',
            'password'=>'required|string|min:6',
            'phone_number'=>'required|string|min:10',
            'role_name'=>'required|string' 
        ]);
        
        $role_a = $request->role_name;
        if ($role_a  == 'صاحب متجر'){
            $role=Role::select('role_id')->where('role_name','صاحب متجر')->first();
            $user->roles()->attach($role);
            return response()->json($user);
        }
        elseif ($role_a  == 'مشتري'){
            $role=Role::select('role_id')->where('role_name','مشتري')->first();
            $user->roles()->attach($role);
            return response()->json($user);
        }
        $user=User::create([
            'first_name' => $request->first_name, 
            'last_name' => $request->last_name, 
            'email' => $request->email, 
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password), 
            'phone_number' => $request->phone_number,

        ]);
```

And my use statement:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Models\User;
use App\Http\Models\Role;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
```

And my route:

```
Route::post('/register','App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@register');
```

and this what I have in tables:

[image]

**Note**: I didn't use custom packages like spatie for example

Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: Can you show your routes ?

Comment: What is the version of laravel you are using ?

Comment: Laravel 9
I have a mistake with routes, and I corrected it
Thank you so mush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss adding the Request class as an argument into your method. Your method should look like this:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
  //after validation
  $data = $request->validated();
}
```

Dont forget to add `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` in your use statement.

Comment: I try it but it also show me an error:"ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Http\Request::Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\{closure}(), 0 passed"

Comment: can you show the use statments in your class?

Comment: `use Illuminate\Http\Request;  
use App\Http\Models\User;  
use App\Http\Models\Role;  
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;`

Comment: Can I see your route as well and the entire `register()` method. Something is definitely wrong somewhere

Comment: I edit the post.. I change something in controller then I face another error :(

Comment: If you did not change the folder structure of Laravel, then your models should be in `App\Models` and not `App\Http\Models`

Comment: Awww thank you so mush, I didn't notice that!